# Is it possible to create Sqlite database without creating any table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to just create a database which could be used to hold different tables. But at first, i just want to create a database without any table and then check if a database file exists then issue the create table command. So, that the table creation could be done at later period but database creation could be done initially at the android application startup

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'm pretty sure you can do that. If you're using a SQLiteDatabaseHelper, all you have to do is just not create a table in onCreate, then write a creatTable() function to handle that for you later. If you're using Context.openOrCreateDatabase(), it creates an empty database. I'm not sure how to check if a database already exists, however.

One thing to keep in mind is that the database might not actually be created if you don't have a table in it. It wouldn't hurt anything to just create the database right before you make the first table.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29) link. Try using getWritableDatabase(). According to the documentation this should create the database if it exists, or open up an existing database.

If you have problems with this, then just create the database with a table like [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), then remove the table right after. Ie:

```
    public static void clearDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
        db.delete(sqlite_sequence, "name = '"
                + DATABASE_TABLE + "'", null);
}
```

The above code deletes all entries in the table. To remove it completely you could try this

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DATABASE_TABLE + "'");
```

Hopefully this helps!
Cheers

Comment: getWritableDatabase() is not working and the second approach is just a way. I wanted to know that is there any function or support provided by sqlite3 to create an empty database

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you try to achieve yet for me it sounds like you just use the created/not created database state as a flag . If so maybe better just handle this was a sharedpreference variable and create the database when you actually need it.

Comment: I just wanted to know is there a way to create an empty database in android to make it act as honeycomb. So could any1 tell me a way to create an empty database

Comment: the context class has the required methods for that, Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory))

Answer (score 0):

SQLite will not create the database until you make some change to it.

A harmless change that doesn't involve a table would be to execute [this](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html):

```
PRAGMA user_version = 0
```